# Making trajectory_planner stick to a given trajectory

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I wish to make trajectory_planner stick to a predefined trajectory and stop sampling, which functions must I modify? Will this require essentially rewriting trajectory_planner.cpp?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31484/making-trajectory_planner-stick-to-a-given-trajectory/) by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 365 on 2012-04-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you looked at the pose_follower package or other packages from navigation_experimental?

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1